# Consistent Alternating background across multiple ItemsControl instances and their subviews

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, alternating

For this layout ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh5ZF.jpg)) I'm using multiple child `ItemsControl` objects within an `ItemsControl` object to layout the data. I need the main background for these sub-entries to alternate between `LightGray` and `White`. I'm using `AlternationCount` but as you can see, when it goes into another level of sub-entry, the alternation index isn't right. (I guess this is expected since I've set an AlternationCount for the sub `ItemsControl`)

Is there any way to have each item entry's alternation index take into consideration the item above it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `RelativeSource` `Binding` to get the `AlternationIndex` of the parent `ItemsControl`. I don't have your XAML so is difficult to know exactly what you've got going on.

```
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    AlternationCount="2">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Item}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```